# Force transmitted to mass through spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, vibrations

Consider the following system, where we have a mass $m$ between two springs with constant $k$. A force $F$ is applied to the spring on the left, and the spring on the right is fixed.

[image: Spring-system mass]

What is the force acting on the mass? If $F$ was periodic, I could calculate the transmissibility

$$ F_m = F \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\beta^2)^2}}, \beta = \frac{\omega}{\sqrt{2k/m}}$$

but what about non-periodic forces? All my calculations eventually lead to force $F$ being applied directly to the mass, which makes little sense to me.

EDIT:

The case I am most interested in is when the force $F$ is an Heaviside step function.

Comment: By "non-periodic" do you mean constant, or just varying without any set repetition?  If you just meant constant force; try a free body diagram on the system.

Comment: Can't you take the square root of the argument in the denominator?

Comment: When you say you're most interested when the force is a Heaviside Step function; do you mean the transient response to the step function, or just the steady state after the force is applied and the system is at rest?

Comment: @JMac, transient. At steady state, the force will be equal to $F$, right?

Comment: The time average of the forces exerted by the springs are zero.  So, sure, the amplitude of the net force exerted on the mass is the same as the amplitude of the force F.

Comment: I'm confused. Your question is asking "what is the force" but you explicitly state that the force is a step function in your edit.

Comment: @KyleKanos the applied force is a step function. I wanted to know how this force was transmitted to the mass considering it was surrounded by springs. My calculations yielded that the force on the mass would be F, and the answers to this question seem to confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of physics problem is idealized to focus on the parts that are instructive. So motion is often frictionless. Ropes and pulleys and springs are massless. The reason for this is to make rope, pulleys, and springs just be things that exert forces on masses. That way you can calculate forces and accelerations on the masses, without adding the complexity of acceleration of the springs.

It sounds like this problem is static, or motionless. That tells you the total force on any masses must add to $0$.

The way to think of a spring is that it pushes outward or pulls inward with equal and opposite forces on each of its ends. The magnitude of the force is proportional to the distance it is compressed.

So the problem is saying that a force is applied to the left spring. The springs compress until forces are balanced, and then nothing moves.

If you put your hand on the spring to push it, your hand will be motionless. However much your arm pushes on your hand, the spring pushes back with an equal force, so your hand is motionless. This would be expressed in the problem by saying the end of the spring is motionless. This is much like the wall, except the wall cannot move.

So if you press with force F on the spring, the spring is compressed until it pushes outward with force F. That means it is pushing with force F on the mass. So force F is applied indirectly to the mass.

Comment: How would this work if the problem was dynamic? Forgot to mention I was interested in that on the original question. Already edited it.

Comment: It still remains true that there is no point in including the left-hand spring.  Whatever the force is at the left end, it's the same as at the right end.  So you can just say that the force acts directly on the block.

Comment: This might be easier if the displacement was a step function.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume the spring to be massless, the sum of the forces on the spring will be zero. Otherwise, the spring would experience infinite acceleration due to Newton's second law. The force applied to the left side of the string thus equals the force applied to the mass by the right side of the string. This is what your calculations already indicated.

The situation would be different if instead of controlling the force on the spring, you would be controlling the position of the left end of the string. In that case, the solution would become less trivial.